# access private members in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I have a class A, which have a field val declared as private.
I want to declare a class B, that inherit from A and have an access to val. 
Is there a way to do it on C++?

I want to do it because I need to overload some functions of A, without changing A code at all.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't access another's class private field, doesn't matter if it's an ancestor. If you have no public getter/setter methods, you are out of luck.

Comment: This question would be better if you posted a complete, minimal example program we can compile and test that illustrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can "shadow" the data / member function in A with data in B. It wont modify the data in B at all. It's not the same as overloading, but in some contexts it may do the job.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Quick answer: You don't. Thats what the `protected` key-word is for, which you want to use if you want to grant access to subclasses but no-one else.

`private` means that no-one has access to those variables, not even subclasses.

If you cannot change code in `A` at all, maybe there is a `public`/`protected` access method for that variable. Otherwise these variables are not meant to be accessed from subclasses and only hacks can help (which I don't encourage!).

Comment: What you think about private pure virtual method in parent class? why compiler show error to override it? it's mean they are inheriting ?

Comment: @UnKnown: yes, pure virtual functions need to be overridden in order to use the base class.

Comment: It's mean private members inherit? because after declaring pure virtual method as private compiler error me to override.

Comment: Having a pure virtual private function kind of defeats its purpose: to establish an interface, that inheriting classes must implement.

Comment: @Constantinius That's not true; f.e. have a look at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#private-virtuals

Answer (score 27):

***Private members of a base class*** can only be accessed by base member functions (not derived classes). So you have no rights not even a chance to do so :)

`class Base`

- ***public***:    can be accessed by anybody
- ***private***:   can only be accessed by only base member functions (not
  derived classes)
- ***protected***: can be accessed by both base member functions and derived
  classes

Answer (score 13):

Well, if you have access to base class, you can declare class B as [friend class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class). But as others explained it: because you can, it does not mean it's good idea. Use protected members, if you want derived classes to be able to access them.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this isn't rated higher because it does two things: 1)gives correct answer (most answers here basically say that it's not possible probably due to the fact the `friend` classes are not that widely used so they just don't know about this feature and/or because they come from a language that doesn't have something like that) and 2)mentions that it's not a good idea. A better answer would be to say WHY it's not a good idea of course. :)

Answer (score 6):

It is doable as describe in this Guru of the Week - [GotW #76 - Uses and Abuses of Access Rights](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm). But it's should be considered a last resort.

Comment: I knew already #define trick, but this page is marvellous! Thanks!

Comment: This is the only answer that solves my actual problem - The vendor's library has a couple of buggy methods, and I'd rather provide fixed versions of them than copy and modify the whole library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define it as `protected`. Protected members are inherited to child classes but are not accessible from the outside world.

Comment: after inheriting protected members, you can provide public access. then we should avoid to keep personal data in protected access specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the private members of a base class say A through an inherited member function of A

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    int a;
    
    public:
    A(){};
    A(int val){a=val;};
    
    int get_a(){//To access a private variable it must be initialized here
        a=10;
        return a;
    }
};

class B: public A{
    int b;
    
    public:
    B(){};
    B(int val){b=val;};
    
    void get(){
        cout<<get_a();
    }
};

int main(){
    A ob1(2);
    cout<<ob1.get_a()<<endl;
    
    B ob2(4);
    ob2.get();
    
    return 0;
}
```