# Inheritance of private and protected methods in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, private, protected

I know, there are no 'real' private/protected methods in Python. This approach isn't meant to hide anything; I just want to understand what Python does.

```py
class Parent(object):
    def _protected(self):
        pass

    def __private(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        self._protected()   # This works

    def bar(self):
        self.__private()    # This doesn't work, I get a AttributeError:
                            # 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__private'
```

So, does this behaviour mean, that 'protected' methods will be inherited but 'private' won't at all? 
Or did I miss anything?

Comment: you have to call it this way, assume c is an instance of Child `c._Parent__private()`

Comment: Isn't it working as it should? AFAIK private methods are not inherited. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241462/access-private-members-in-inheritance

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Python has no privacy model, there are no access modifiers like in C++, C# or Java. There are no truly 'protected' or 'private' attributes.

Names with a leading double underscore and no trailing double underscore are *mangled* to protect them from clashes when inherited. Subclasses can define their own `__private()` method and these will not interfere with the same name on the parent class. Such names are considered *class private*; they are still accessible from outside the class but are far less likely to accidentally clash.

Mangling is done by prepending any such name with an extra underscore and the class name (regardless of how the name is used or if it exists), effectively giving them a *namespace*. In the `Parent` class, any `__private` identifier is replaced (at compilation time) by the name `_Parent__private`, while in the `Child` class the identifier is replaced by `_Child__private`, everywhere in the class definition.

The following will work:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        self._protected()

    def bar(self):
        self._Parent__private()
```

See [*Reserved classes of identifiers*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) in the lexical analysis documentation:

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes.

and the referenced [documentation on names](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named Ham will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.

Don't use class-private names unless you *specifically* want to avoid having to tell developers that want to subclass your class that they can't use certain names or risk breaking your class. Outside of published frameworks and libraries, there is little use for this feature.

The [PEP 8 Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has this to say about private name mangling:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes
>   that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with
>   double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes
>   Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is
>   mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name
>   collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the
>   same name.
>
> Note 1: Note that only the simple class name is used in the mangled
>   name, so if a subclass chooses both the same class name and attribute
>   name, you can still get name collisions.
>
> Note 2: Name mangling can make certain uses, such as debugging and
>   `__getattr__()`, less convenient. However the name mangling algorithm
>   is well documented and easy to perform manually.
>
> Note 3: Not everyone likes name mangling. Try to balance the need to
>   avoid accidental name clashes with potential use by advanced callers.

Comment: I knew, it had something to do with this name mangling thing. I knew I could access to the method from outside the class by _Parent__private, but I just didn't get why I couldn't call it inside the inherited class. I didnt knew, that subclasses get their own `__private()`, thank you very much for this clear answer!

Comment: What about `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()`? A child would not be able to inherit these methods from its parent?

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain: Those names contain underscores at the end too, not just at the start of the name. That's a *different class of names*. See the [documentation I linked to](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: Thanks, but the docs there aren't giving me much more useful info. I've moved this to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444733/python-inheritance-of-dunder-methods

Comment: @Martijn: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I'm not using a `pythonic style` when trying to make all variables private inside a class and then use `getters` and `setters` for these private variables. Well, I should google this question about usage of private variables.

Comment: mypy throws an error for this solution:
`error: "Child" has no attribute "_Parent__private" `

Is this accessing of mangled private name outside of the class poor practice?

Comment: looks like it (for C++ but probably applicable here): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784107/5392289

Comment: @OliverAngelil: that sounds like a mypy bug more than anything. You may want to review why you are explicitly having to use the mangled name.

Comment: I think mypy is trying to discourage the practice of accessing private variables outside of a class.

Answer (score 16):

The double `__` attribute is changed to `_ClassName__method_name` which makes it more private than the semantic privacy implied by `_method_name`.

You can technically still get at it if you'd really like to, but presumably no one is going to do that, so for maintenance of code abstraction reasons, the method might as well be private at that point.

```
class Parent(object):
    def _protected(self):
        pass

    def __private(self):
        print("Is it really private?")

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        self._protected()

    def bar(self):
        self.__private()

c = Child()
c._Parent__private()
```

This has the additional upside (or some would say primary upside) of allowing a method to not collide with child class method names.

Comment: This won't work in the case of a call inside the Child with the Parent private method

Answer (score 10):

By declaring your data member private :

`__private()`

you simply can't access it from outside the class

Python supports a technique called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

This feature turns class member prefixed with two underscores into:

> _className.memberName

if you want to access it from `Child()` you can use: `self._Parent__private()`

Answer (score 8):

Also [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says

> Use **one leading underscore** only for **non-public** methods and instance
>   variables.
>
> To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to
>   invoke Python's name mangling rules.
>
> Python mangles these names with the class name: if `class Foo` has an
>   attribute named `__a`, it cannot be accessed by `Foo.__a`. (An insistent
>   user could still gain access by calling `Foo._Foo__a`.) Generally,
>   double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts
>   with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.

You should stay away from `_such_methods` too, by convention. I mean you should treat them as `private`

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, I encountered it and found a nice workaround.

In the case you name mangled on the parent class because you wanted to mimic a protected function, but still wanted to access the function in an easy manner on the child class.

```
parent_class_private_func_list = [func for func in dir(Child) if func.startswith ('_Parent__')]

for parent_private_func in parent_class_private_func_list:
        setattr(self, parent_private_func.replace("_Parent__", "_Child"), getattr(self, parent_private_func))
```

The idea is manually replacing the parents function name into one fitting to the current namespace.
After adding this in the init function of the child class, you can call the function in an easy manner.

```
self.__private()
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, in the second case Python perform "name mangling", so the name of the __private method of the parent class is really:

```
_Parent__private
```

And you cannot use it in child in this form neither