# What do these outline symbols in the pydev eclipse editor mean?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using pydev with eclipse helios. From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean) I can see that the yellow diamond indicates a protected member... in java. What does this mean in my pydev outline?

For the record, the once with circles are initialized as none e.g. `self.id = None` while the two with diamonds are initialized using an object factory `self.object = object_factory(stuff in here)`[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python by convention an "_" means protected. And two "__" means private. The following is an image with both of cases:

[image]

So, in PyDev that diamond means the same that in Java. A protected member.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261517/inheritance-of-private-and-protected-methods-in-python) you have a good explanation about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Private members of the class. All members/methods in python are implicitly public. By doing _name we declare them private. So Eclipse is showing them as a special type in Outline view.

Comment: Yep, reproduced that. I suppose that does make sense, I just got hung up on python not having 'true' private members. Additionally it looks like prefacing with 2 underscores makes the same symbol as private for Java

Comment: There a lot of stuff different in Python. It takes time to get used to.

Comment: The diamond don't means private members of the class.

Comment: `“Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.` Is from Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) So: _ is private instance variables, __ is private class variables.

Answer (score -1):

I see the two with the diamond begin with an underscore ("_"). While not enforced, this is a sign that the member fields are 'private' and should not be accessed by the user of the class.

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private for more details.

Comment: No private, protected. See my answer.

Comment: Hence the apostrophes. There is no conecpt of 'private' or 'protected' variables in Python; you can force it to mangle the name by using a double underscore prefix, but you can still access and use that particular mangled member in your code.

Comment: Your answer should say 'protected' not 'private'. There is no concept of `private` or `protected` in Python, however there is a convention: `_` stands for 'protected' while `__` for 'private'. And is true `__` forces a mangled name while `_` don't. That's why is "harder" to access directly to a `__` member than to a `_`.