# How super() works with private variables?

Tags: python-3.x

There is an interesting question on python 3.5. For example I've smth like:

```
class A:
  __x = 0
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__x = x

  def set_x(self,x): __x=x
  def get_x(self): return x

class B(A):
  __y = 0
  def __init(self, x, y)
    self.__y = y
    super(B, self).__init__(x)

  def set_y(self,y): __y=y
  def get_y(self): return y

  def toString(self): return "x = {} and y = {}".format(self.__x,
                                                        self.__y); 
test = B(7,3)
test.toString()
```

Why do I have an error here: "B object has no attribute _B__x", if the method `super()`  let me to use all methods of parante class?

Sure, if I write, like:

```
def toString(self): return "x = {} and y = {}".format(self.get_x(),
                                                      self.__y);
```

It works well!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261517/inheritance-of-private-and-protected-methods-in-python - you shouldn't be using `__double_leading_underscore` names.

Comment: Also, your setters don't actually work.  You always need to do `self.name = value`.  `name = value` creates a local variable.

Comment: Also also, there's no need to initialise instance attributes as class attributes, just set them in `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get access to private variables/members through super().
So in order to access B.__x, you will have to do

```
def toString(self): return "x = {} and y = {}".format(self._B__x,
                                                    self.__y);
```