# Django, Python inheritance: Exclude some fields from superclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, inheritance, django-models

I have inheritance between Employee and Manager classes. Employee - superclass, Manager - subclass.

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    
class Manager(Employee):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    """
    Here I don't want the 'name' and 'address' fields of Employee class.
    (I want other fields of Employee and 'department' field of this 
    class to be stored in Manager table in database)
    """
```

How can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if this was possible, that would leave the `Manager` without a name. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: In other languages you would make the fields of `Employee` `private` as opposed to `public` or `protected`.

Comment: Why you don't use foreingkey?

Comment: Yes I definitely want these fields to be completely removed from Manager

Comment: Put the fields you do want in an _abstract_ model, and let both Employee and Manager inherit from that? But really, I feel inheritance shouldn't be used at all here.

Comment: I would very much like to upvote this question but I would not unless one  of the answers that provides a solution is accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make private variables in python class using 2 underscores (`__`), check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261606/3042057) example for more.

However they will store that values in child object as there is no such thing as private or protected in Python.

But another approach can work for Django. In Django model fields are stored depending on their value (`CharField`, `DateField` and etc.) but if you will make item value `None` or any other static value (ex. `"string"`), that should solve your problem:

```
class Manager(Employee):
  name = None
  address = None
  # other_stuffs.
```

In that example, Manager should not have name and address columns in database and when you will try to access them, you will get `None`. And if you want to get `AttributeError` (Django raises that when object hasn't requested key) then you can also add property:

```
class Manager(Employee):
  name = None
  @property
  def name(self):
    raise AttributeError("'Manager' object has no attribute 'name'")
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd use 3 classes:

```
class BaseEmployee(models.Model):
    # All your common fields

class Employee(BaseEmployee):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

class Manager(BaseEmployee):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I think that achieves what you wanted.

Comment: the accepted answer is not working in my case on Django 3.2
and this is a much OOP way to achieve this thank u!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 3 classes `AbstractEmployee` with `abstract = True`, `Employee` and `Manager` as shown below. `abstract = True` makes `AbstractEmployee` class an abstract class so a table is not created from `AbstractEmployee` class while each table is created from `Employee` and `Manager` classes and to remove the inherited fields `name` and `address` from `Manager` class, set `None` to them:

```py
class AbstractEmployee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True # Here
    
class Employee(AbstractEmployee):
    pass
        
class Manager(AbstractEmployee):
    name = None # Here
    address = None # Here
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```